# If a string is in Unicode 3.2.0 NFD, is it safe to compose it into Unicode 6.1.0 NFC (using Python 3.3's unicodedata.normalize function)?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.3, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

Consider this code in Python 3.3:

```
import unicodedata

foo = 'some unicode string that contains characters decomposable to Unicode 3.2.0 NFD'
bar = unicodedata.ucd_3_2_0.normalize('NFD', foo)
bla = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', bar)
```

Is the last statement guaranteed to work? I guess the better question is: is there any NFD sequence in Unicode 3.2.0 that is not covered by Unicode 6.1.0 (which is the default in Python 3.3)?

I realize that, at the byte level, `bla` may not be exactly the same as `foo`, because combining marks may have been in a "non-standard" order in `foo` to begin with (e.g. \u0071 **\u0307 \u0323**, instead of \u0071 **\u0323 \u0307**. I would think it's fine as long as `bla` *appears* to be the same as `foo` to the end-user, instead of looking corrupted/scrambled.